# Last letter change based on number incrase

Tags: php

How can i change the last letter of an word like:

You have 10 weeks left, well i want to change weeks to week based on number incrase if is 1 i want to be: 1 week<- and if 2, to be : 2 weeks<- in echo result

I have this process:

```
function get_weeks_remaining($date, $expire){

        $difference = strtotime($expire) - strtotime($date);
        return floor($difference / 604800);

}
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "table"); 
$nume = $user->data->username;
$id = $user->data->id;
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
$expire_date = 'May 07, 2016';
$remain =  get_weeks_remaining($date, $expire_date);

$sql = "SELECT `id`,`remain` FROM `week`";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
while(list($id,$remain) = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "you have $remain weeks left";
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(list($id,$remain) = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 if($remain > 0 and $remain < 2){
   echo "you have $remain week left";
 }else{
   echo "you have $remain weeks left";
 }
}
```

or just do `echo "you have $remain week/s left";`
i hope this will help you

Comment: accept this answer if your problem is closed. thanks.

Comment: i have to wait some little time for accept. Done now, thanks again!

Comment: One more question, if the script reaches the end date and shows me 0 week left, is there a way  to make the script to do an mysql insert ? I want on end date to block a user, and for blocking i want to insert value 1 and for unblock value 0 in my user table on my site.

Comment: the simplest code is to add it into the `if else` condition

Comment: Done ! :) Thanks bro! Good day for you!